# How do I corectly pass the paramters into the URL?

Tags: android, google-maps, url

```
 void url_get(double lati, double longi) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location="+lati+","+longi+"&radius=3000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am not getting any output for this.

However when I replace the lat and long with hardcoded values,I get the correct output.Could you please help me out on this?

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY"
```

Is the right way to put it when hardcoded.

Comment: what are the values of lati and longi?

Comment: `I am not getting any output for this.` In that case you had that exception! The least you could do is posting the value of `url` you get.

Comment: try logging `lati` and `longi` before the creating the URL

Comment: The values of lati and longi are pased through another function.That function is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https")
                .authority("maps.googleapis.com")
                .appendPath("maps")
                .appendPath("api")
                .appendPath("place")
                .appendPath("search")
                .appendPath("json")
                .appendQueryParameter("location", "17.739290150000002,83.3071201")
                .appendQueryParameter("radius", "6000")
                .appendQueryParameter("types", "hospital")
                .appendQueryParameter("sensor", "true")
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "MY_KEY");
        String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: You are not making use of `double lati, double longi` at all. Or of doubles. So you avoid the problem completely.

Comment: No no.I want to use lati and longi in my url.Just like how I wrote in the first case.But it was not giving the right output.